# Adding controls to custom panels in the designer

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls

What i have at the moment is a custom control which has three panels, navigation panel, content panel and a header panel which all works as it should do... what it doesn't allow me to do is when i add this control to a windows form in the designer it doesn't then allow me to add controls to the panels within the custom control. Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to "bubble" a Controls features when place in a custom UserControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785376/how-to-bubble-a-controls-features-when-place-in-a-custom-usercontrol)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants to know how to do this I was searching for the wrong thing as to why I couldn't find anything on the topic

[How to drop controls onto a panel in a user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383907/how-to-drop-controls-onto-a-panel-in-a-user-control)